# Which video player can play 1080p mkv on iPad Mini Retina?

Tags: mediaplayer

The iPad Mini Retina comes with the new A7 chip. However, playing back of a 1080p MKV is still sluggish using VLC. I'd like to know whether other paid video players are better in handling 1080p MKVs?

Some information about the MKV:

- 1920x1080, x264 10bit
- AAC 5.1 720 kbps

Comment: The problem with the MKV is, that it's not hardware accelerated.

Comment: best bet is to keep with vlc and use a lower bitrate mkv, or a mov. I've heard good things about nPlayer, too.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler How to tell whether a MKV is hardware accelerated or not?

Comment: Only H.264 files are hardware accelerated. MKV is a wrapper that can wraps a lot a encoding format, but wraped H.264 is very uncommon. So suppose it's not.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler H.264 video in an MKV wrapper is in fact hardware accelerated. 10-bit H.264 is not, so any video app you use with these files might struggle with them.

H.264/MKV files are extremely popular among file sharing sites (not implying anything here, but this is what I see) and 10-bit files are gaining popularity with anime watchers.

Answer (score 1):

Give AVPlayerHD a try. I can't say I've tested 10bit 1080p video on it with an iPad Mini Retina, but it used to work flawlessly for 10bit 720p video on an iPad 2. Since there's a big difference in specs between the two iPads, I don't think  you'll have issues playing your videos with that app.

Answer (score -1):

If you Have a Have a Mac computer,have a try on Macgo Mac Blu-ray Player. It has AirX function. With its help, Blu-ray can be played on iOS devices. Such as iPhone, iPad and iPod Touch,iPad Mini Retina.